# MYSQL Select Rows after specific Date (row type is varchar)

Tags: mysql, date, varchar

I'm trying to select all columns after a specific date but the trick is the "date" column is varchar

I have this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y') > '10-10-2000'
```

as an example and I want to select all users whos birthday is after the 10/10/2000 but this just returns all rows.

Anybody got a clue what's wrong?

Comment: Just aside: is there any reason date is not TIMESTAMP or any more semantically right type than VARCHAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a data and a string. I would use `CAST`:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y') > CAST('2000-10-10' AS date)
```

Also note that I changed the format of the second to match what mysql expects. You could also use STR_TO_DATE here.

Answer (score 0):

I think mysql dates are usually yyyy-mm-dd which means you should change the string at the end to 2000-10-10.

Try that and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what format the string birthday is in, now you're saying it is e.g. 12/31/2001. Is that right?

If you have multiple strings, consider using the same STR_TO_DATE-formatting:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%/d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(some_date, '%m/%/d/%Y')
                                                           AND STR_TO_DATE(another_date, '%m/%/d/%Y')
```

More info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date